# Error when using regression based estimator

Tags: r, lm

I am using the `KoutParametersEstim()` function from the `StableEstim` package to estimate distributional parameters for the time series `RRP` shown in the table called [`SA_PRICE`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2owgs5eejyn6eje/SA_PRICE.txt?dl=0).  So when I run the following code:

```
KoutParametersEstim(SA_PRICE$RRP)$Estim$par
```

I am receiving this error:

```
Error in lm.fit(A %*% X, A %*% Y, method = method, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

This is when I apply the function to the full data set.  Strangely, the function works  well on portions of the data, e.g. the first (or last) 1000 observations.  Not sure what the issue is.  I do not believe that I have any `NA/NaN/Inf' in my data.  It seems something is happening with the computation of the modulus ...

Comment: Any non-finite values in `A %*% Y` (which is `y` inside `lm.fit`)?

Comment: Please don't provide data via dropbox (I and many others won't log in there just to answer some question on Stack Overflow). Copy the data into your question body (preferably the output of `dput(yourdata)`). Also, show code that reproduces the error. In short, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: I have edited the question to give a better reproducible example.  I believe copying the data to the body of the question would get a bit messy because there are almost 9000 observations.  I don't believe that you have to login to dropbox to see the file

Comment: Can you add the code to the question, where you read in your data?  Where you define SA_PRICE.